# How to install Apache Tomcat 9 using apt-get?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, tomcat

I am trying to install Apache Tomcat using `apt-get` but it produces this error:

```
apt-get install tomcat9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tomcat9
```

I updated my Kali Linux to latest but that didn't fix the error.

Comment: to find out if this package is in the repository you can i.e. use `apt-get update; apt-cache search tomcat` (it'll query the APT cache) or the APT package searching utility `apt-file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat 9 isn’t available in the repositories (yet). Your best option is to install one of the binary distributions [available from Apache](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi).

Comment: Let me try it, will update here